# How to combine two input with same name?

Tags: php, html, forms, html-input

I'm trying to combine two input with same name. One part will be disable but user can see the random value and other part will be given by user.

```
[<div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="ProductCode">Product Code</label>
      <input  name="prid" type="text\[\]" class="form-control" id="prid" placeholder="Product Code" value="value">
</div>][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCrCd.png

Comment: If you know first part already - what's the point of outputting it as `input`? Create simple `span` or whatever html-element.

Comment: if i put span can i input the values to data base?

Comment: Where does first part come from?

Comment: randomly generated

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question correctly, but it seems to be simple. You can combine two input with same name using "class" html element.